# how to add nickname calumn in user list wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

**we we want to add 'nickname column' in user list WordPress...**

and also the filter for the *nickname ..*

```
    function new_modify_user_table1( $column ) {
        $column['Nickname'] = 'Nickname';
        return $column;
    }
    add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'new_modify_user_table1' );

 function new_modify_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'phone' :
            return get_user_meta($user_id );
        default:

    case 'Nickname' :
            return get_user_meta($user_id );
        default:
    }
    return $val;
}
```

i have try to used the Search Results

get_user_meta() | Function but proper result i have not getting so please given the solution on it...
1.can you please give us solution on both how to get the nickname in column i.e "nickname"..

2. and also the want to filter for the nickname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_user_meta($user_id, $key, true)` where `$key` can be one of the following:

```
user_pass, user_login, user_nicename, user_url, user_email, display_name, nickname, first_name, last_name, description, rich_editing, comment_shortcuts, admin_color, use_ssl, user_registered, show_admin_bar_front, role, locale
```

For example in your code you can use something like this:

```
 function new_modify_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'Email' :
            return get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_email', true);
        default:

    case 'Nickname' :
            return get_user_meta($user_id, 'nickname', true );
        default:
    }
    return $val;
}
```

Comment: Great! Please do not forget to mark this as approved answer, thank you!